# Question about meaning of the word "crushing" in a supposedly impartial piece of news?

Tags: word-meaning

> Sisi secures **crushing** win in Egypt presidential vote.
> <sub>Source: [Euronews.com, *Sisi Secures Crushing Win in Egypt Presidential Vote*](http://euronews.com/2014/05/29/sisi-secures-crushing-win-in-egypt-presidential-vote/)</sub>

My question has to do with the meaning of the word "crushing". Does the headline imply that many of the electorate who are against the winner are losing their hopes?

I have my doubts if the word "crushing" means "landslide winning".

I checked a dictionary, but cannot decide if it here really refers to winning by large number or the losing or even suppressing of hope.

Comment: **[crushing](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/crushing)** (adj.) "complete and achieved very easily. *'a crushing defeat/victory'*"

Answer (score 3):

A *crushing defeat* could mean either a loss by a large margin (being crushed by the winner) or a very disappointing loss (crushing the spirit) — usually both at the same time.

A *crushing win* means a landslide victory (crushing the opponents).